# Factorizing a polynomial of Degree 5

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got this question, once, and I have not been able to solve it. It is:-

Factorize $x^5+x^4+1$

Comment: Your hint is "the cube roots of unity".

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг You mean I can write this as $x^5+x^4+1^3$ ?

Comment: No, the cube roots of unity other than 1 are roots of the polynomial. Can you see why?

Comment: We  know that if $\omega$ is  a complex cube root of $1$, then $1+\omega^4+\omega^5 = 0$. We also know that $1+ \omega+\omega^2=0$, and this is the smallest polynomial satisfied by $\omega$. Hence, it follows that $1+x+x^2 $ divides $x^5+x^4+1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one nice way of doing it, avoiding all cube roots of unity etc.

\begin{split}
x^5+x^4+1 &  = x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 - x^3-x^2-x \\
& = \frac{x^6-1}{x-1} - x(x^2+x+1) \\
& = \frac{(x^3-1)(x^3+1)}{x-1} - x(x^2+x+1) \\
& = (x^3+1)(x^2+x+1) - x(x^2+x+1) \\
& = (x^3-x+1)(x^2+x+1)
\end{split}

You can't factorize further.

Comment: I like this very much!  +1

Comment: Wow. But I didn't know about the cube root of 1 thing.

Comment: All good you did not know,  it lead to a far simpler answer. Thank you,  @SimpleArt